# CWP7 - mod_rewrite not working?

Tags: centos, mod-rewrite

Recently I was forced to migrate from cPanel to CentOS Web Panel and there is a case-sensitive issue with file names, so "filewhatEver.jpg" is not being found in a url "filewhatever.jpg" (had no problem before in cPanel).

This site (there are 4 hosted) .htaccess have only the basic configuration for WordPress sites:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

mod_rewrite is active (listed in active modules), but when I try:

```
RewriteMap insensitive tolower:
RewriteRule ^[\/]*(.*)$ /${insensitive:$1} [R,L]
```

No luck. *Edit: gives me a "Internal Server Error".*

Any idea?

Comment: "when I try .... No luck" - What do you mean by "no luck" exactly? Where are you putting those directives? Are you saying that when you were using cPanel, the server was not case-sensitive? ie. requesting `filewhatEver.jpg" served "filewhatever.jpg"?

Comment: It doesn't work, return me an Internal Server Error. The directives are in the htaccess file of the site in question. I tried "RewriteRule (.*\.(jpg|gif|png))$ https://example.com$1 [P,NC]", in this case the server stills up, but simply doesn't work, no effect. Edit: forgot to say, but yes, exactly that. If the request was using lowercase to a file with uppercase, there was no issue in cPanel. Now the file is not found.

Comment: You can't use `RewriteMap` in `.htaccess` - this is only permitted in the main server config - that's why you are getting a 500 error. cPanel runs on Linux - which is a case-sensitive OS. So, if it wasn't case-sensitive then there must have been additional directives in the server config to enable this. Do you have access to the main server config?

Comment: I simply did the migration from my old server to the new, and never had such problem before, so yes, requests were case-insensitive as far I know.

Comment: Are your underlying URLs/files all lowercase, or are they mixed case?

Comment: Some are mixed, so there are links like "example.com/file.jpg" pointing to "/uploads/File.jpg", and yes, I have full access to the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the underlying filenames are mixed case, you can't use a rewrite map to convert the request to lowercase as it will still fail to match. (Incidentally, rewrite maps can only be defined in the main server config, not in `.htaccess`.)

However, you can use mod_speling (one `l`) to achieve the case-insensitive file matching.

You need to first make sure that mod_speling in enabled on your server. Then add the following directives to your virtual host config (or `.htaccess` file):

```
CheckSpelling on
CheckCaseOnly on
```

Note, however, that there is an additional overhead to using mod_speling and an external redirect is triggered when the file is found. The redirect is necessary for SEO, but will be bad for server performance if you are requesting image resources in mixed case (which is what this looks like?).

I would assume mod_speling must have been enabled by default on your old cPanel server, as this would not have been case-insensitive by default.

mod_speling is really only for incorrectly cased requests from external sites. Any internal requests should really be "fixed" to match the correct case of the underlying file.

Comment: Thank you. Added: "CheckSpelling On CheckCaseOnly On" to the site htaccecss. httpd.conf edited and "speling_module (shared)". No effect, url in lowercase pointing mixed filename keeps returning a 404.

Comment: Did you restart Apache after modifying httpd.conf / enabling mod_speling? Try adding this to your server config (or virtual host), instead of `.htaccess`. A potential "problem" with your existing `.htaccess` directives are that you rewrite the URL when the request does not map to a file (I think this happens before mod_speling).

Comment: I did. I'll edit my question, just noticed in fact it seems to be working because an image named like "My_File.jpg" is now loading, but other "My-File.jpg" is not - maybe an additional hyphen instead of underscore problem?

Comment: If you need to correct for hyphen/underscore then mod_speling could possibly do this as well, by removing the `CheckCaseOnly on` directive - or setting this to `off`. However, correcting this URL in your site would be preferred.